# Baffling implode result in SonataAdmin

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using SonataAdmin and Symfony2 for my application. I have EntryAdmin which is a list of entries by facilitators from different agencies. When an agency user is logged in, I limit them only to entries by facilitators contracted to them, which I do by customizing the list query.

as below:

```
        $facilitator_array = array();
        foreach($facilitators as $facilitator)
        {
            array_push($facilitator_array,$facilitator->getId());
        }
        $query->andWhere($query->getRootAlias().'.facilitator IN (:facilitators)');
        $query->setParameter('facilitators', implode(", ",$facilitator_array));
```

The resulting query does not give me results because the array is quoted as a string as shown below.

```
 SELECT e0_.id AS id0, e0_.name AS name1, e0_.tel AS tel2, e0_.email AS email3, e0_.knows_olx AS knows_olx4, e0_.device_type AS device_type5, e0_.defrauded AS defrauded6, e0_.is_verified AS is_verified7, e0_.is_new AS is_new8, e0_.created_at AS created_at9, e0_.updated_at AS updated_at10, e0_.created_by AS created_by11, e0_.updated_by AS updated_by12, e0_.facilitator_id AS facilitator_id13, e0_.channel_id AS channel_id14 FROM entries e0_ WHERE e0_.facilitator_id IN ('51,61,81,91,101,371') ORDER BY e0_.id ASC
```

How can I remove the quotes ('51,61,81,91,101,371') because I've done all I could with no avail

Comment: Don't use implode. Just set the parameter to the array of ids.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ids = array_map(function($element){return $element->getId();}, $facilitators);
$query->andWhere($query->getRootAlias().'.facilitator.id IN (:facilitators)');
$query->setParameter('facilitators', $ids);
```